# React, manually move an element of the html/dom, to be in a different container

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I have implemented tinymce in my react code, but it generates a html similar to this

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="root">
    <div class="StyledGrommet-sc-xxx" > </div>
</div>
<div class="tox tox-silver-sink tox-tinymce-aux" style="position:relative;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But this code gives me some issues with the overflow because of this class , StyledGrommet-sc-xxx, which im not able to change for w/e reasons.

The ideal solution would be that react would render the html like this, but for some reason tinymce, decided to render it ouside of root (its a floating toolbar, part of tinymce components)

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="root">
    <div class="StyledGrommet-sc-xxx" > </div>
    <div class="tox tox-silver-sink tox-tinymce-aux" style="position:relative;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was thinking about somewhoe manipulating the dom in useEffect to append it there, but so far i havent been able to do so.

This is the component (simplified)

```
export const Editor = ({ value, onChange }: Props) => {
  const editorRef = useRef<EditorType>(null);
  const [showSymbolModal, setShowSymbolModal] = useState(false);
  const [showImageModal, setShowImageModal] = useState(false);
  const [showIframeModal, setShowIframeModal] = useState(false);
  const [showHTMLModal, setShowHTMLModal] = useState(false);

  const onAddSymbol = (code: string) => {
   
  };
  const onAddImage = (file: File) => {
    
  };


  const onAddIframe = (iframe: string) => {
    editorRef.current.execCommand(IFRAME_ADD_COMMAND, true, iframe);
    setShowIframeModal(false);
  };
  const onUpdateHTML = (html: string) => {
    editorRef.current.setContent(html);
    setShowHTMLModal(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {showImageModal && (
        <UploadImageModal
          onImport={onAddImage}
          onCancel={() => {
            setShowImageModal(false);
          }}
        />
      )}
      {showSymbolModal && (
        <AddSymbolModal
          onAddSymbol={onAddSymbol}
          onCancel={() => {
            setShowSymbolModal(false);
          }}
        />
      )}
      {showIframeModal && (
        <AddIframeModal
          onAddIframe={onAddIframe}
          onCancel={() => setShowIframeModal(false)}
        />
      )}
      {showHTMLModal && (
        <HTMLModal
          html={editorRef.current.getContent()}
          onUpdate={onUpdateHTML}
          onCancel={() => {
            setShowHTMLModal(false);
          }}
        />
      )}
      <Editor
        onEditorChange={(...props) => {
          console.log(props);
        }}
        onInit={(evt, editor) => {
          editorRef.current = editor;
          editor.addCommand("open_chars_dialog", () => {
            setShowSymbolModal(true);
          });
          editor.addCommand(IMAGE_BUTTON_COMMAND, () => {
            setShowImageModal(true);
          });
          editor.addCommand(IFRAME_BUTTON_COMMAND, () => {
            setShowIframeModal(true);
          });
          editor.addCommand(HTML_BUTTON_COMMAND, () => {
            setShowHTMLModal(true);
          });
          editor.ui.registry.addButton("parapraph-button", {
            text: "parapraph",
            onAction: api => {
              editor.formatter.apply("p");
            }
          });
        }}
        initialValue={value}
        init={{
          height: 500,
          menubar: false,
          object_resizing: false,
          browser_spellcheck: true,
          plugins: [
            "link",
            "lists",
          ],
          branding: false,
          contextmenu: false,
          formats: {},
          toolbar:
            "paragraphs | bold italic underline strikethrough | subscript superscript | bullist numlist | link unlink | undo redo",
          toolbar_groups: {
            paragraphs: {
              icon: "blocks",
              items: "parapraph-button h2 h3 h4 h5 h6"
            }
          }
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const addImageToEditor = async (file: File, editor: EditorType) => {
  
};
```

I was thinking about doing something like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    
    const rootDiv = document.getElementById("root");
    const editorDiv = document.querySelector(".tox");
    console.log(rootDiv)
    console.log(editorDiv)
    
    if (rootDiv && editorDiv) {
      rootDiv.appendChild(editorDiv);
    }
  }, []);
```

But it doesnt seem to work